# Solr index time boost

Tags: solr, dih

I 'm importing data using DIH to solr. In my schema.xml I have all my fields defined. I know there are two types of boosting techniques, query time or index time. 
Is it possible to boost fields by assigning weight to them during index time.

For example, if there are 4 fields
id, title, description & keyword.
Then I would like to "boost" the score if the search string is in title as compared to keyword.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using DIH you can boost the whole doc, not a specific field, as documented [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Special_Commands).

But if you intend to boost a field, like title, this is easy to do on query time, in fact it is easier to do, and to change too. Why do you want to do it at index time, any special reason?